# Google Tag Manager preview mode not working on click

Tags: google-chrome, google-tag-manager

This is not a problem with viewing the GTM console on my domain.

When I click the "preview" button my GTM interface refresh, but it just won't go into preview mode! Never had this problem before and I've tried closed and opened chrome, disabled cache in devTools and tried it in incognito. Nothing of this works.. Any ideas?

I have admin with publish rights for my account.

Comment: The most common problem with this is that 3rd party cookies are disabled - gtm needs to set a cookie from the tag manager domain to enable the preview.

Comment: Mhm, it's so strange because I've got that enabled and before the holidays it worked like a charm.

Comment: Have you tested in other browsers to verify that the issue isn't Chrome-specific?

Comment: It's Chrome-specific, tried both safari and firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it!
One of my Chrome extensions blocked it for some reason I don't know.

It was the extension "Ghostery" that caused the problem and  when I deactivated it "preview and debug" started working.
Now I just have to find out a way to still use the extension and keep GTM working, like it did before christmas.

Comment: Thats strange that it worked before christmas and not now. Google has a team that actually makes call to all extension providers if they block the GTM-snippet. Dont worry they will fix it in no time, or send the GTM-team a mail

Comment: Think I found that one out to. I marked tagmanager.google.com to be a trusted site in Ghostery and seems to work.

Comment: This should not be necessary, extensions should not block tagmanager.google.com from the first place.

Comment: Other ad blockers, like Ublock, will also prevent it from showing

Comment: I even installed a brand new browser, "Brave", to make sure nothing was installed and I have a clean cache, but I haven't been able to use the preview window once yet. I can't do anything until I get this working!

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if you are blocking third-party cookies, the GTM Preview/Debug won't turn on.

Answer (score 0):

I've never got Preview mode to work in Chrome.It does work using Opera. You can get an add-on for Opera that will allow you to use all Chrome extensions in Opera.

Comment: We'll it worked on chrome before the holidays so it's really strange why it won't work suddenly after two weeks. I'd rather not switch to Opera.